# Property of Type ObservableCollection<UnknownType>

Tags: c#

I want to provide a function that returns an `ObservableCollection`, where the type is any of the model classes.

```
internal ObservableCollection<_t> DetailsCollection(Type _t)
{
    ObservableCollection<_t> col = new ObservableCollection<_t>();

    _t obj = (_t)Activator.CreateInstance(_t);

    col.Add(obj);

    return col;
}
```

The reason for doing this, is that some Model classes have Properties of the type `ObservableCollection<AnotherModelClass>`, e.g. for master-detail entities. I want to pass the instance of said class to a generic function, that fills the properties with values from the database.

Here is some example code that might help to explain what I want to do:

```
    class CustomerModel : ModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<AddressModel> Addresses { get; set; }
}

class InvoiceModel : ModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}


class ItemModel : ModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<SupplierModel> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

class ViewModelBase 
{

    public void LoadModelData(ModelBase ent)
    {
        //fill properties with values from the database
        //I got this working for the System types, like Id and Name
        //and for the properties that have a type derrived from ModelBase
        //like the Customer property of Invoice. But it should
        //look sth. like this

        foreach (DataRow row in recorddetailstable.Rows)
        {
            DetailModel det = new DetailModel() { Id = row["IdInDb"], Name = row["NameInDb"] };
            ent.property.add(det); 
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: No, you cannot turn a run-time type (`Type t`) into a compile-time type (`<T>`).

Comment: How would you pass instances of classes to a generic function? What does this generic method of yours look like? If the signature of this generic method is written in correctly, the compiler might be able to infer the type argument from the type of the passed instanced. And this generic method would then be able to return an `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T` is actually the inferred type from the instances passed to this method.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, are you looking for a method like:
     public ObservableCollection<T> DetailsCollection(T model)
     {
     ....
     }

Comment: You can pass in a `System.Type` for the desired type parameter (say `ItemModel`) of the ObservableCollection, use `Type.MakeGenericType()` to create a `System.Type` for the realized generic type (`ObservableCollection<ItemModel>`), create one with Activator.CreateInstance, create instances of the items that go in it, add them by casting your ObservableCollection to `System.Collections.IList`, etc. etc. What you can't do is make the return type of that method use a type parameter not supplied at compile time. But that wouldn't be useful anyway, so that's OK.

Comment: Whether any of that is *worth* doing is a separate question. `internal ObservableCollection<_t> DetailsCollection<_t>() {...}` is trivial of course, but `_t` has to be known at compile time.